# Get Data from XML in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I parse an XML-File with jQuery and put the Values in specific Div-Container.
But the Problem now is, that the Markup is wrong.
Here is my jQuery:

```
   $(xml).find('section').each(function () {

        $('.main').append('<div class="tab-container"><div class="tab">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</div>');

        $(this).find('sub').each(function () {

            $('.main').append('<div class="tab_content">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</div>');

            $(this).find('date').each(function () {

                $('.main').append($(this).attr('name') + '<br />');

                $(this).find('detail').each(function () {

                    $('.main').append($(this).attr('from') + ' - ' + $(this).attr('to') + '<br />');

                });

            });


        });

        $('.main').append('</div>');


    });
```

And that is the HTML-Markup

```
<div class="main">
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab">Brand Events</div>
</div>
    <div class="tab_content">Brand Events</div>
</div>
```

I need the div with the class "tab_content" inside the div with the class "tab-container". What is the mistake in my script??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly appending jquery objects with incomplete syntax could be the problem

An easier way is just to keep the reference to the objects, and append the correct ones. It makes it easier to read, and easier to adjust...

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/GtvFr/

```
$('#fakedata').find('section').each(function () {
    var main = $('.main'),
        section = $('<div class="tab-container"></div>');

    section.appendTo(main);

    $('<div class="tab">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</div>').appendTo(section);
    $(this).find('sub').each(function () {
        var sub = $('<div class="tab_content">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</div>');

        sub.appendTo(section);
        $(this).find('date').each(function () {
            sub.append('<br />' + $(this).attr('name'));
            $(this).find('detail').each(function () {
                sub.append('<br />' + $(this).attr('from') + ' - ' + $(this).attr('to') + '<br />');
            });
        });
    });
    $('#innerHTML').text($('.main').html());
});
```

which gives the following output:

```
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab">section1</div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        sub1<br>date1<br>from - to<br>
    </div>
</div>
```